# How to include a hyperlink in the body text of a custom password protected form?

Tags: functions, password, code

I have customized and styled the password protected form that shows up for protected pages by adding code to the functions.php file of my theme. This all works fine, but I would like to add a hyperlink to the text displayed on this form that leads to a page where people can sign up to receive the password. Does anyone know how this works?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Cheers!

Comment: Can you add the code you included in your functions.php.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the code you added to functions.php is a filter for 'the_password_form', where you've got something like:

```
function my_protected_post_form () {
    $myCustomizedFormCode = '<form action=....'
    return $myCustomizedFormCode;
}
add_filter ('the_password_form', 'my_protected_post_form');
```

So where you have the instructions to the user in that custom form code string, you just need some simple HTML to provide the link you want. For example:

```
    '[...]To view this protected post, enter the password below, or <a href="http://example.com/passwordsignup">request a password</a>.[...]'
```

Comment: Great @Emily :) Please accept this answer if it covers everything you need.